# How to fix this method to return all the connections a node, in a position i, make with other nodes

Tags: python, networkx

Given a digraph with 2 nodes (0, 1):  0 is connected to 0 and 1. And 1 is connected to 0. Like this adjacency matrix:

```
Adj = [[1,1], # 1 represents connections and 0 no connection
       [1,0]]
```

My desired output is the following:

```
v = [{0,1}, {0}]  # Node 0 connects to itself and 1. Node 1 connects to node 0.
```

Which means that, the node 0 who is located at v[0], connects to node 0 and 1. The node 1 which is located at v[1], connects only to node 0. So, basically it should tell the nodes whose the node at position i is connected to

What I have done:

```
>> import networkx as nx
>> import numpy as np
>> arr = np.array([[1,1],[1,0]])
>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>> G = nx.from_numpy_array(arr, create_using = nx.DiGraph)
>> L = []
>> for i in range (N): # N is the amount of nodes in the graph, in this case 2.
>>    aux = set(nx.edge_bfs(nx.Graph(G.edges), i))
>>    U.append(aux)
>> print(U)

Output: [{(0, 1), (0, 0)}, {(1, 0), (0, 0)}]
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? What is your expected result? How is what you're getting different?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to use the nx.descendants method.

```
    for i in range (0, q):
      x = nx.descendants(G,i)
```

That snippet give all nodes reacheable from a source node, except for self loops.